# entity framework nullreference exception

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

I saw other similar questions, but I can't manage to apply other solutions.

**Here is the code**

```
Dim da1 As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(Date.Today, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim dataQuery As String = da1.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).PadLeft(10)
Dim errori = db.TRANSAZERROR.Where(Function(t) t.DATA.PadLeft(10) = dataQuery)
```

`transazerror.data` is a `nullable` varchar field (yes it's not a datetime) and it also contain a time, so I'm using padleft to get only the date in the format dd-MM-yyyy.

What I want is to select all record that have `data=today` so the `errori` var should be a list of records, but the code above returns

> Nullreferenceexception

I don't know why.

I'm using EF 6.

Thanks for your hints!

**Exception detail:**

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Riferimento a un oggetto non impostato su un'istanza di oggetto.
  Source=transazErrorLog
  StackTrace:
       in transazErrorLog.Form1.log() in I:\Documenti\Vs15_Projects\transazErrorLog\transazErrorLog\Form1.vb:riga 22
       in transazErrorLog.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in I:\Documenti\Vs15_Projects\transazErrorLog\transazErrorLog\Form1.vb:riga 9
       in System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       in System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       in System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       in System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       in System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       in System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       in System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       in System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

**EDIT:**
I tried to use another filed of the db, it's a date field set to nullable=false, even with this I get the nullreference exception...
I turn the question around: how can I get a list of record using entity framework?

Comment: EF6 does not support `PadLeft` method, hence the exception would be different. This sounds more like EF Core client evaluation exception. You'd better include the exception stack trace, otherwise the question will be closed as the usual NRE duplicate.

Comment: Looks like the problem is in your code (`db` variable being `null`), voting to close.

Comment: I tried with this Dim errori = (From errors In db.TRANSAZERROR
                      Where errors.DATASCARICO = Date.Today).ToList() but I still get NRE. Datascarico is not nullable and it's a date type

Answer (score 1):

You might check `transazerror.data` is not null on `where` statement first.

You can use `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method

**like this**

```
Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.DATA) AND t.DATA.PadLeft(10) = dataQuery
```

Comment: Dim errori = db.TRANSAZERROR.Where(Function(t) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.DATA) And t.DATA.PadLeft(10) = dataQuery)
Still returns nullreferenceexception

Comment: Also with Dim errori = db.TRANSAZERROR.Where(Function(t) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.DATA) ) alone, it throws the error

Comment: Could you check `db.TRANSAZERROR` object is exist? and Is `transazerror.data` type string on EF Model?

Comment: Yes it exists and transazerror.data is a String type. The nullable property on the EF model is set to (None)

Comment: I also tried to use another field that is a datetime, using date.today (instead of dataquery) but I get the same error. Even if this other field is nullable=false

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying `TRANSAZERROR.DATA` is nullable, imagine you have a null value there in one of the records. Now when you try to do PadLeft on NULL, it will throw your error.

The solution, I can suggest is before doing PadLeft inside your LINQ query, first check whether `t.DATA` is null and IF NOT perform the PadLeft.